# stopping a function from taking 100% of ram

Tags: python, memory, memory-management, out-of-memory, pycryptodome

I am making an app that has encryption with PyCryptodome, here is the code that does the encryption:

```
class Cipher:
    def __init__(self, password: str, key: bytes = None):
        self.key = PBKDF2(password, key if key else password_as_key(password), dkLen=32)
        self.cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv=get_random_bytes(16))

    def encrypt(self, data: bytes) -> bytes:
        return self.cipher.encrypt(pad(data, AES.block_size)) + self.cipher.iv

    def decrypt(self, data: bytes) -> bytes:
        encrypted_data = data[:-16]
        iv = data[-16:]
        self.cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv=iv)
        return unpad(self.cipher.decrypt(encrypted_data), AES.block_size)
```

While this class works great with most files, however, files that are too large (i tested on this file: https://github.com/szalony9szymek/large) crash the program with a memory error. i want to make sure that even if the files are that big, the program would have some sort of a defense to make sure the app doesn't crash (and hopefully can show a loading screen instead, and keep encrypting when more memory can be allocated).

how can i implement such a thing on this Cipher class?

some extra data:
OS - windows 11 Home
ram - 8.00 GB (7.68 GB usable)
processor - 12th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1235U   1.30 GHz

Comment: try to use Python generators to read N bytes and perform operations one block at a time instead of trying to encrypt/decrypt the entire file in one go. For large files (>1GB) you may want to consider using  `mmap`

Comment: Encrypt the file in chunks, perhaps 16 KB, 64 KB, or 1 MB per chunk. However, you need to know what you are doing with encryption, otherwise, you will have weak encryption. Do not trust the code posted here. Google search and read a few detailed white papers on how to implement secure encryption.

Comment: @OM222O
your solution half worked, it did give me slightly more time before the program crashes (a couple times it didn't even crash), but it still crashes some times, can you please reccomend me a couple other things i could do similar to ```mmap``` and reading in chunks?

Comment: @JohnHanley don't worry, this isn't just this encryption that i'm implementing, i didn't want to make the code more complicated, so i removed things like authentication, permissions etc. those are in another class called User that wraps this class. this class is only meant for the encryption/decryption of bytes

Comment: @user21815993 can you update the question with your new code? If you use those ideas correctly you shouldn't have any memory issues. Preferably post all of your code (including the "User" class that you mentioned) so we can reproduce what you have done instead of guessing